# Nested Pipeline - Apache Beam - Flink Runner - Running Local - Failing on Local Cluster

Tags: java, apache-flink, streaming, apache-beam

For Context, my use case is to read from an unbounded source, in this case I am using aws SQS.
From each message, I am wanting to generate pipelines dynamically that read from another location, transform and write.

Since I need to read the data from another source (which would be bounded), I would still have to generate more pipelines, hence the need for nested pipelines as the parent pipeline(SQS) should be constantly running triggering the consequent read based on the message.

I attempted to do a simple implementation of running nested pipelines which runs when running on intellij but when I spin up a local cluster and specify the master its not able to print the log in the second pipeline. Getting the following errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Pipeline execution failed
...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: <SENSORED>)
...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
...
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
...
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Pipeline execution failed
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Pipeline execution failed
...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: <SENSORED>)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.runners.core.metrics.MetricsContainerStepMap
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:78) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2003) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1870) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2201) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.OptionalFailure.readObject(OptionalFailure.java:122) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1046) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2357) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:617) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:602) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:589) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.util.SerializedValue.deserializeValue(SerializedValue.java:67) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.accumulators.AccumulatorHelper.deserializeAccumulators(AccumulatorHelper.java:208) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:131) ~[flink-runtime-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:128) ~[flink-clients-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:403) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$26(RestClusterClient.java:708) ~[flink-clients-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:403) ~[flink-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
```

here is the sample code :

```
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
        p.apply(SqsIO.read().withQueueUrl("https://examplesqsurl/abcd"))
                .apply(Window.<SqsMessage>into(new GlobalWindows()).discardingFiredPanes().triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))))
                .apply(MapElements.into(strings()).via(SqsMessage::getBody))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext context, OutputReceiver<String> out) throws Exception {
                        log.info(context.element());
                        Pipeline newPipeline = Pipeline.create(context.getPipelineOptions());
                        newPipeline.apply(Create.of(context.element()))
                                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
                                @ProcessElement
                                public void processElement(ProcessContext context, OutputReceiver<String> out){
                                    log.info("I am running in the second pipeline " + context.element());
                                    out.output(context.element());
                            }
                        }));
                        newPipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
                        out.output(context.element());
                    }
                }));
        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
```

I am able to see the log statement in the first ParDo in the cluster but not the second one

Flink cluster version is 1.15.4

beam-runners-flink-1.15

beam.version is 2.49.0

P.S : Complete newbie with apache beam & Data Processing. If there is a better approach I am all ears!